# Kitura Swift App not compiling on Heroku

Tags: swift, heroku, kitura

Create a Kitura app locally and compiles and builds successfully. But when attempting to deploy to heroku after a while, I get the following output:

/tmp/build_cbc1c98480abd8ace78731a677031c0a/.build/checkouts/Kitura.git--211144618449703330/Sources/Kitura/RouterRequest.swift:56:33: error: use of unresolved identifier 'RegularExpression'remote:                 let regex = try RegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive]) remote:                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ remote: Foundation.NSRegularExpression:1:12: note: did you mean 'NSRegularExpression'? remote: open class NSRegularExpression : Foundation.NSObject, NSCopying, NSCoding {

The version of swift used is 3.1 and I specified the same version when pushing to heroku via the .swift-version file.

This is the Package.swift used

Version of Kitura used is 1 major 7 minor

Trying other versions of swift e.g. 3.1.1 results in hanging - to the point that heroku cancels due to timeout. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please note that you experience discrepancies of Swift on Mac and on Linux. You probably checked it on your Mac, while Heroku runs Linux.

Second, `RegularExpression` was replaced by `NSRegularExpression` in this pull request https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura/pull/1107. You should not experience this problem starting from Kitura 1.7.4. It means that you probably use Kitura version before 1.7.4, that could happen if you have `Package.pins` file that specify an old Kitura version. You can either remove that file, or run `swift package update` to update it.

To verify the actual version of the Kitura package used, `cd` to `.build/checkouts/Kitura.git-XXXXXXXXXXX` directory, run `git tag` there and check the latest tag.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. Yeah - I was using version 1.7. Updating it to 1.7.4 allowed it to compile on heroku. Thanks again!